# SORT FILTER function with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm an enthusiastic novice working on a Google sheet. I realise this formula isn't pretty and there's probably a better and more logical way to do this. The formula I'm trying to use works in as much as it filters the correct rows I want, but I can't get them displayed in the order I want.

This works for the filter part...

```
=(FILTER(LBACCsV2!N11:AR,LBACCsV2!O11:O="I",(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ1")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ2")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ3")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ5")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ6")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ7")))
```

But, I want to sort by Column LBACCsV2!AB which is column 15. If I adapt the formula with SORT like this...

```
=SORT(FILTER(LBACCsV2!N11:AR,LBACCsV2!O11:O="I",(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ1")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ2")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ3")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ5")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ6")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ7"),15,TRUE))
```

It doesn't work and I get an error message which says...

"Error

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1013, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1."

Please don't shoot me down, as I said, I'm a novice who didn't what a spreadsheet was a while ago. Any help warmly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have a misplaced closing bracket. The two parameters of the sort function appear INSIDE the filter function. Try

```
=SORT(FILTER(LBACCsV2!N11:AR,LBACCsV2!O11:O="I",(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ1")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ2")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ3")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ5")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ6")+(LBACCsV2!S11:S="MQ7")),15,TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was starting to do my head in.